# Split a column value into two columns in a SELECT?

Tags: postgresql, select, split

I have a string value in a varchar column. It is a string that has two parts. Splitting it before it hits the database is not an option.

The column's values look like this:

```
one_column:
'part1 part2'
'part1 part2'
```

So what I want is a a result set that looks like:

```
col1,col2:
part1,part2
part1,part2
```

How can I do this in a SELECT statement? I found a pgsql function to split the string into an array but I do not know how to get it into two columns.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

```
select split_part(one_column, ' ', 1) AS part1, 
       split_part(one_column, ' ', 2)  AS part2 ...
```

Comment: Worked, but I needed to give the columns names to avoid an error: `SELECT split_part(one_column, ' ', 1) AS part1, split_part(one_column, ' ', 2) AS part2 ...`